# WI-FI 802.11 speed depending on distance

Tags: math, distance, equation, wifi

can someone help me with a document containing the theoretical exact speed of different standards of 802.11 WI-FI depending on the distance (1 to 10 meters) ?
like if there is an mathematical equation that gives how the speed decrease with distance ,or software tool, or a table that gives how speed decreases every 1 meter for example , i need something very exact.
THank you :)

Comment: Buff, you're question is quite difficult to fulfill, wifi has too many variables to get into account that can impact on the performance, like what type of area you look at, walls, busyness, electronic devices ... etc, I even had onces interferences with my microwave! Please be more accurate, like type of room/area/whatever you want to use as common ground

Comment: Thank you :)Yes i know,it depends of many factors... ,but i just need the theoretical informations ,not real one's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure distance effect while dismissing accompanying factors is negligeble due to the following facts:

1. Assuming the transmission is continuous - the data arrives continuously to the target, there is only an initial latency till the first packet reaches the destination (if the transmission isn't continuous, there is not much sense in talking about speed - clearly, the max speed isn't reached in this case).
2. Data is carried upon radio waves which travel at the speed of light. 802.11 speed limit is much lower than theoretical limit imposed by the speed of light - therefore any distance impact is practically non-existant.

What should be taken into account, though, is the fact that with distance the interferences to the wireless link grow significantly, leading to decrease in speed. But again, it's a side effect of distance (e.g., it's eliminated if both the transmitter and the receiver are sealed in Faraday cage).