# Capabilities of Samsung Galaxy S2 Wi-Fi network card

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, galaxy

I am doing a research and trying to find the distance between 2 samsung S2 galaxy phones, using Wi-Fi, by measuring RTT.
For that, in order to get the highest accuracy, I need to access the network Phy, and see the exact time the packet has left one cellphone, and the exact time it arrives back, before it has been processed in the LAN card (again, I need a very high accuracy).

Is it possible? Did someone succeed in accessing the LAN card physical layer on samsung S2 galaxy?

BTW - my cell phones are "rooted".

Thanks in advance,
Tzach

Answer (score 0):

It's not too feasible at SW level. There are several factors that severely limit your ability to perform such measurements:

- Data is being propagated at speed of light, any timer that you might have access to, is no match for such resolution.
- You need to do at least some processing to understand that the data has arrived; similarly, there is a delay from when you measure transmission start till the packet actually leaves to the air. These delays are much more significant than the actual time of travel in the air.

Also see a related question: [WI-FI 802.11 speed depending on distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608804/wi-fi-802-11-speed-depending-on-distance/21934091#21934091)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I worked a lot on this ability at SW level, and as you have written - it is not feasible. My question is about testing this ability at HW level ("talk with the PY"). Do you know if it can be done with Samsung S2 galaxy?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I worked a lot on this ability at SW level, and as you have written - it is not feasible. My question is about testing this ability at HW level ("talk with the PY"). Do you know if it can be done with Samsung S2 galaxy?